# forgot to save the mnemonic(bip39) when generating wallet from cli

Tags: cli, help

i used generated keypair output to file so there are only bytes that are saved and got my public key but i still can't got my private key. Any help or hint how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the output json file you have the entire public and private key.  If you want the mnemonic and you didn't save it you'll have to generate a new keypair.  This is irreversible by design.

The first 32 values in the YOUR_KEYPAIR.json is the private key.

If you have Sol in the wallet, generate a new keypair, write down the mnemonic and then transfer the Sol from the old address to the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is it possible to use that private key to import it into Phantom wallet please?

Comment: so there is no way i can import  it to a browser wallet ? there isn't a way that would allow me to convert those byte private key into seed ?

Comment: I am not sure on the import.  It’s certainly possible to do in theory.

Comment: What do you mean convert private key into a seed?  You may be able to copy/paste the key into the wallet but I’m not sure.

Comment: i means, the browser wallet accept hex private key while the json is byte format (maybe it accept byte format but i'm not sure)

Comment: You can convert bytes to base58.

Comment: amazing so to restore my hex private key i just need to convert the first 32 bytes (which are basically the private key) and just import it to my wallet, right?

Comment: going to try it, coming back to you !

Comment: Presumably.  I hope it works for you.  I never do it like this, but if a wallet accepts base58 for private key it would work.

Comment: Good news ! Worked fine ! But the thing is that i used the 64 bytes keypair instead of only 32 bytes to recover my base58 seed. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150443/discussion-between-david-lampach-and-pandakungfuu).

Comment: That’s the behavior I would expect.  You keep saying seed, and I really don’t know what that is in this context.  But glad it worked.  I would expect a wallet to import a keypair, not just a private key, so this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to David Lampach who explained me that i need to encode the bytes to base58 to have access to my wallet. Ty lot sir, i don't know at all how solana works

In future if someone would have same problem as me

first import bs58 crate to your cargo project

then use this code to get your private key seed to connect browser wallet

```
fn main() {
    let vector_of_your_64_bytes = vec![];
    let data = bs58::encode(vector_of_your_64_bytes);

    println!("{:?}", data.into_string());
}
```